# first and last k digits of number n^n

Tags: c++, algorithm

i have written a c++ code for generating first and last k digits of a number as large as 10^9. (k<=9).

```
cin>>n>>k;
    cout << (unsigned long)floor(pow(10.0, modf(n*log10((double)n), &dummy) + k - 1)) << " ";  // code that prints the first k digits
    long long int ans = foo(n,k);  // function that prints the last k digits
    if(ans==0)
    {
     for(int i=0;i<k;i++) cout << "0";
    }
    else{
            stringstream ss;
            string s;
            ss<<ans;
            ss>>s;
            if(s.size()!=k)
            {
                 for(int i=0;i<(k-s.size());i++)
          s="0"+s;
            }
            cout<<s;
   }
```

where function foo() is:

```
long long int foo(int n, int k)  // code of the function
{
  long long int m=1;
  for(; k > 0; k--) m*=10;

  long long int r=1, t=n % m;
  while(n)
  {
    if (n % 2)
      r = r * t % m;
    t = t * t % m;
    n >>= 1;
  }

   return r;
}
```

this gives me output as:
if given 9 and 3 as inputs, it gives first and last 3 digits of 9 to the power 9 (9^9) i.e. 387 and 489. But I m still missing out some test cases.
Can anyone please help me finding out the test case for which my code wouldn't work ?

1 ≤ n ≤ 109, 1 ≤ k ≤ 9
the problem statement: http://www.codechef.com/problems/MARCHA4/

Comment: if you know there is a case where you code doesn't work, why don't you describe that case. it sounds like homework where your task is to figure it out. then you're not well served by having someone on Stack Overflow figure it out for you -- would spoil your learning completely

Comment: From that problem description, it looks very much like you're supposed to find a method that works for VERY large `n`, e.g. "find the first and last 4 digits of 2413 raised to the 2413".

Comment: IMHO, Annotating your code with comments will help you get a faster answer.

Comment: no thats not a homework, i was just solving a problem of an online judge, i have written the code myself. I m just in the search of the wrong test case for which my solution fails.

Comment: @ben my code gives 1290 and 7453 as result.. isn't that right ??

Comment: @Ben Voigt - he is using modular logarithmic exponentiation; the code will work very fast for `n^n` as large as `MaxInt^MaxInt`. At least for the last digits, haven't really checked the first digits part yet.

Comment: why are you so confident there is a failed test case?  also, are you willing to consider simply finding the number explicitly and then using string methods?  it would probably require a language with unlimited size integers (python, mathematica, etc) but would be almost trivially simple

Comment: @vaibhav: Looks correct to me... I guess I just wasn't understanding your first sentence the way you meant it.  It seems that "find the first and last k digits of a number" and "a number as large as 10^9" aren't supposed to mean the same "a number"?

Comment: There are only 109*9 test cases, try them all!

Answer (score 2):

If `n^n <= 10^9`, in which case your code seems to work fine. However, if you allow bigger `n`, say `11^11`, and ask for the last 4 digits of that, which are `0611`, your code will only print `611`. Basically, it doesn't print any leading zeroes when it should.

Comment: How can any number in decimal have leading zeroes? I'm pretty sure that it's kind of implicit in the point of decimal that you don't need them.

Comment: Where in the question do you see `n <= 10^9`?  It's the number he's taking digits of, i.e. n^n, that is bounded by 10^9.

Comment: @DeadMG - the problem asks for the last `k` digits, and 0 is a digit. The problem doesn't ask for a number, it asks for a string. @Ben Voigt - true, that's what I meant actually, thanks.

Comment: @IVIad: No, I'm pretty sure your interpretation was what the asker **meant**, I just was wondering if I was reading the question wrong.  Good to know I'm not.

Comment: i have updated my solution, it now contains the leading zeroes but the judge still says wrong answer.

Comment: @vaibhav - can you give us the address of the problem on the judge you're using, if it's an online site? That way we can test for ourselves and tell you exactly what's wrong. I'm guessing precision errors since you're using `pow` and `log10`, but I'd like to see the problem statement.

Comment: @IVlad: Damn, you wrote last digits, and I read first digits.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't really answer the question, and its almost trivially easy, but I figure it might be worth sharing.  If there were a "long comment" capability I'd be using it.

EDIT: just noticed using str instead of repr will eliminate the L on its own

```
def firstAndLastDig(k, num):
    s = str(num)
    return (s[:k], s[-k:])

def firstAndLastDigSelfExp(k,n):
    return firstAndLastDig(k,n**n)
```

Overflow is not an issue (the only thing is dealing with the L if you use repr instead of str),

```
firstAndLastDigSelfExp(6,12)
('891610', '448256')

firstAndLastDigSelfExp(42,491)
('209417336844579728122309696211520194012462', '160453713040914743773217804810667483135091')
```

And neither are leading zeroes

```
>>> firstAndLastDigSelfExp(4,9)
('3874', '0489')
```

This isn't do say the modular logs and stuff aren't cool - on the contrary I really liked reading about how you did this without generating the entire number. I didn't know about modf at all until reading OP's question and the body of foo is very interesting.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is using floating point.  Finding the first digit of a number actually requires perfect precision.

Unfortunately, the contest judge evidently doesn't understand that "number of significant digits" != "number of correct digits".

Perhaps there is some clever way to exactly compute (n**n, n = 10**9) without exhausting memory, but finding the first digits of a very good estimate is simply not the same as finding the first digits of the answer.

Answer (score -1):

Assume that `k = 9`.  Now, `m = 1e9`, and `t <= 1e9 - 1`.
`t * t` then may be as high as `1e18 - 2e9 + 1`, which needs ... 59.8 bits.

Ok, not a problem with a 64-bit `long long int`, which has 63 bits of magnitude (and 1 of sign), but I'll leave this here so others don't repeat the same analysis.

Answer (score -1):

Are you told that `n` is a positive integer?  For example, `(-8)^(-8)` is perfectly well expressible in decimal but your program can't handle it.